# Read Timeout Intellij Idea TFS 2012

Tags: intellij-idea, tfs

Using fairly slow TFS system(can't be speed up) run on slow hardware.

This causes Read Timeout's.

Project cann't be checked out via the Intellij therefore, is it possible to configure retry period or increase timeout in some way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did this Read timed out problem appear just recently or was it always?

Which error did you get? such asTF400307: The download operation timed out after waiting 601 seconds for a response from the server.

There is a workaround to increase the time-out :

1. Open the **registry editor** (go to start menu and in the run dialogue type regedit).
2. If you are on a 32-bit machine, then navigate to the key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\TeamFoundation\RequestSettings. Alternatively, if you are on a 64-bit machine, then navigate to the key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\TeamFoundation\RequestSettings.

a.       If TeamFoundation\RequestSettings does not exist, then right-click on the TeamFoundations key.

b.       Chose to create a new key.

c.        Name the key **RequestSettings**.

3. Change the value of **DefaultTimeout** to the new time-out time (the time is in milliseconds).

a.       If DefaultTimeout does not exist, then right-click on the key RequestSettings.

b.       Choose to **create a new DWORD**.

c.        Once DefaultTimeout exists, right-click on it and choose modify, and enter the new time (in decimal).

For more detail, you can reference: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ablock/archive/2008/09/16/increasing-the-time-out-time.aspx